# Store collection value to variable

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am having issues storing a value in mongodb to a variable to use within my webpage.

When the user fills out a form on my website, I am trying to figure out what the arrivalTrailer was when the user filled out the arrival form.

So far I have

```
function previousLoad(loadNumber, callback){ 
        CheckCall.find({loadNumber: loadNumber}).sort({date: 'desc'}).limit(1), function(err, arrival){
            if (err){
                callback(err, null);
            }
            else {
                callback(null, arrival[0]);
            }
        }};

    previousLoad(loadNumber, function(err, arrival){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            arrivalTrailer = arrival;
            console.log(arrival);
        }
    });

    console.log(previousLoad.arrival);
    console.log(arrivalTrailer);
```

Both output as undefined when I try to console.log the variables.

Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
async function previousLoad(loadNumber) {
    try {
        let resp = await CheckCall.find({ loadNumber: loadNumber }).sort({ date: -1 }).limit(1)
        return resp[0]
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error ::', error)
        throw new Error (error)
    }
}

/** You can return response from previousLoad but to test it, Call it from here */ 
previousLoad(loadNumber).then(resp => { console.log('successfully found ::', resp)}).catch(err => { console.log('Error in DB Op ::', err)});
```